# MySQL Left Joins with Date Range

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Looking to run a query using multiple left joins. The following query works.

```
SELECT directory.location, sales.covers, labor.hours
FROM t_directory directory
LEFT JOIN t_sales sales
ON sales.id = directory.id
AND sales.business_date = '2011-11-14'
LEFT JOIN t_labor labor
ON labor.id = directory.id
AND labor.business_date = '2011-11-14'
ORDER BY directory.id ASC
```

The trouble comes if I try to query between a date range. Adding a Group By clause has been duplicating rows. Right now I'm actually using two separate queries, which is probably better practice, and a better solution. This is just out of pure curiosity at this point.

Here is what I have so far.

```
 SELECT directory.location, sales.covers, labor.hours
 FROM t_directory directory
 LEFT JOIN t_sales sales
 ON sales.id = directory.id
 AND sales.business_date BETWEEN '2011-11-13' AND '2011-11-14'
 LEFT JOIN t_labor labor
 ON labor.id = directory.id
 AND labor.business_date BETWEEN '2011-11-13' AND '2011-11-14'
 GROUP BY directory.id, sales.business_date, labor.business_date
 ORDER BY directory.id ASC
```

Clearly something wrong with my GROUP BY clause, and perhaps other errors as well.

I am looking for a result like this:

```
| location | covers | labor |
=============================
  loc1     |  300   | 99.40
  loc1     |  325   | 100.50
  loc2     |  250   | 89.00
  loc2     |  275   | 90.20
  loc3     |  400   | 100.00
  loc3     |  500   | 122.90
```

And of course, what I am actually getting is:

```
| location | covers | labor |
=============================
  loc1     |  300   | 99.40
  loc1     |  300   | 100.50  
  loc1     |  325   | 99.40
  loc1     |  325   | 100.50   
  loc2     |  250   | 89.00
  loc2     |  250   | 90.20
  loc2     |  275   | 89.00
  loc2     |  275   | 90.20
  loc3     |  400   | 100.00
  loc3     |  400   | 122.90
  loc3     |  500   | 100.00
  loc3     |  500   | 122.90
```

Any help with getting the expected results would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Here are the tables with sample data that I want to join. They all share a common id.

```
t_directory
| *id | location | 
|100  |   loc1   |
|101  |   loc2   |
|102  |   loc3   |

t_sales
| business_date | id | sales    | covers |
|  2011-11-13   | 103| 4000.00  | 300    |
|  2011-11-14   | 103| 4050.00  | 325    |

t_labor
|business_date | id | hours | 
| 2011-11-13   | 103| 99.40 |
| 2011-11-14   | 103| 100.50|
```

Comment: Try grouping by `directory.location` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected result doesn't really make sense to me. There's no relationship between `sales`  and `labor` rows, so why should a `covers` value of 300 go next to a `labor` value of 99.40? What's tying those two values together? That's why you're finding it hard to write the query to produce the results: you're trying to output two columns where the data in each are not related.

I probably haven't explained that very well. I'm sure someone else can!

Comment: Agreed.  Missing a relationship between sales and labor.   Only thing I can see as a "trend" is that the least cost cover goes with the least cost labor.  but that may not be a hard fast rule.  My first thought was that you needed to be joining from location to sales and then from sales to labor; instead of going back though directory each time.  But since all the joins are based on the same relationships that wouldn't matter.

Comment: I added the tables so you can get an idea. covers are the "cover count" or the amount of people, and they are in in our sales table. Sorry about any confusion.

Comment: So the two tables are related by `business_date`? Add a clause `WHERE t_sales.business_date = t_labor.business_date` to your query - that should do it.

Comment: Tim, I think that may have been the solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-query the group by's distinctly per sales / labor, THEN left join to them.  If you have multiple rows in one table, is it falsely messing up your return record counts, and thus the results...  Try

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
      PreQualifiedIDAndDate.ID,
      PreQualifiedIDAndDate.business_date,
      directory.location, 
      PreQuerySales.TotalCovers, 
      PreQueryLabor.TotalHours
   FROM 
      ( select distinct 
              sales.ID,
              sales.Business_Date
           from t_sales sales
           where sales.business_date between  '2011-11-13' AND '2011-11-14'
        UNION
        select labor.ID,
              labor.Business_Date
           from t_labor labor
           where labor .business_date between  '2011-11-13' AND '2011-11-14' )
         as PreQualifiedIDAndDate

         JOIN t_directory directory
            on PreQualifiedIDAndDate.ID = directory.ID

         LEFT JOIN
         ( select sales.ID,
                  sales.business_Date,
                  sum(sales.covers) TotalCovers
              from t_sales sales
              where sales.business_date between  '2011-11-13' AND '2011-11-14'
              group by sales.ID, sales.Business_Date ) PreQuerySales
            on PreQualifiedIDAndDate.ID = PreQuerySales.ID
            AND PreQualifiedIDAndDate.Business_Date = PreQuerySales.Business_Date

         LEFT JOIN 
         ( select labor.ID,
                  labor.Business_Date,
                  sum( labor.hours ) TotalHours
              from t_labor labor
              where labor.business_date between  '2011-11-13' AND '2011-11-14'
              group by labor.ID, labor.Business_Date ) PreQueryLabor
            on PreQualifiedIDAndDate.ID = PreQueryLabor.ID
            AND PreQualifiedIDAndDate.Business_Date = PreQueryLabor.Business_Date

   GROUP BY 
      PreQualifiedIDAndDate.id,
      PreQualifiedIDAndDate.Business_Date
   ORDER BY 
      directory.id
```